# Angular 2 One route works, another does not

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular 2 with routing and I have one route that works perfectly well and another that does not. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on the second. If I navigate to /event/650 it matches the event/:id route, but if I navigate to /event/2017/04/04 I get "Error: Cannot match any routes".

app.routes.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CalendarComponent } from './calendar/calendar.component';
import { EventComponent } from './event/event.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'calendar',
    component: CalendarComponent
  },
  { 
    path: 'event/:year/:month/:day',
    component: EventComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'event/:id',
    component: EventComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'event',
    component: EventComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/calendar',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Snippet of event.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.params['value']['id']);
};
```

This will log the id if I go to /event/650, but event if I drop the ['id'] keyname I still get the route not found error when I put the year/month/day in the url.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the order of route declarations, with /event first and /event/year/month/day last

Comment: `'event/:year/:month/:day'` and `'event/:id'` is seen as the same route. The last one will be considered.

Comment: I tried changing the order and get the same error. @Erevald: I don't understand why that would be because I'm getting an error not being routed to the 'event/:id' route. Please help me understand if I'm not getting it. Thx

Comment: you either need to implement `children` routes 
OR 
if you have to render the same component, just keep one route with `event/:year/:month/:day` and get the params from injecting `ActivatedRoute`.